# How to detect only objects of a specific category in tensorflow object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

The [object detection notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) demonstrates, how [models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) pretrained on the [COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org/#home) can be used to detect objects on test images. However, the models in the notebook return boxes for detected objects of all categories in the COCO set. How can I use the code to return boxes for objects of only one category? I.e. How can I get boxes for objects of which the model is sure that they are e.g. persons?

Comment: In the object detection code folder, there's a file for visualization. You need to edit that file and keep only relevant object detection values. Remove rest of them (by marking them 0).

Comment: Thanks, I just found it out myself. I will upload a revised notebook here soon , demonstrating the solution .

Answer (score 2):

I have just implemented the solution myself.

check the `def filter_boxes` function in the notebook https://github.com/fera0013/TrafficLightDetection/blob/master/Traffic-Light-Detection.ipynb, to see how the boxes can be filtered by category.

Comment: I'm trying to run you notebook to filter only the person category, but I'm stuck on **Detecting traffic lights in a test image** section. I'm getting an `IndexError: list index out of range` in `ilustrate_detection(image,boxes,classes,model.split('\\')[1])` line. I'm also settings the `id=1`. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: @Minoru if you are running it in unix then replace '\\" with "/" - it'll work.