# How to only detect humans in object detection API Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using `tensorflow` object detection API to detect objects. It is working fine in my windows system. How can I make changes in it to only detect mentioned objects, for example, I only want to detect humans and not all the objects.

As per the 1st comment in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515682/how-to-detect-only-objects-of-a-specific-category-in-tensorflow-object-detection), I have checked the visualization file but didn't find anything related to categories of objects. Then I looked into `category_util.py` and found out that there is `csv` file from which all the categories are being loaded but didnt found this `csv` file in the project. Can anyone please point me into the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume from your question, that you did not finetune your model yourself, but just used a pretrained one from the [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)!?

In this case, I think the model already detect humans AND other objects and you want these other objects to disappear!? For doing so, you just have to change your `label_map.pbtxt` by deleting all classes which you don't need. If you are not sure where to find this file have a look into your `.config` file and search for `label_map_path="PATH"`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that yes I am using pre-trained model which is `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017` for which I have modified the `mscoco_label_map.pbtxt` and removed all object and it only has `person` in it. When testing it with the API, for other objects like `car`, `trucks` it shows bounding box with lable `NA`. How can I even remove this so that it only show bounding box for `person` and not for any other objects. Thanks

Comment: Did you modify the ```num_classes``` parameter in your config file?

Comment: In `objection_detection_tutorial.py` I have `NUM_CLASSES = 90`, Do I have to set it to `1`.? Is there any other file where I have to do the change.

Comment: Yes try setting it to 1.

Comment: After setting it to 1, it still displays all bounding box for other objects

Comment: Which script do you use for detection?

Comment: I am using the objection detection tutorial python file, which I have downloaded from jupyter notebook.

Comment: Okay this script just uses the inference part of the model. It does not change anything, I also don't know where you could adjust the ```num_classes``` parameter. By using thsi script you could check the ```output_dict['detection_classes']``` dictionary and delete all entries, that are not of the class 'person'

Comment: Okay Thank you I will look into this in detail. About the `output_dict['detection_classes']`, it only saves data like `[[ 3.  3.  3.  1.  1.....` what does these values means.? How do we know which class is of person

Comment: These are the ids of each class. The default ```label_map.pbtxt``` (the one with 90 classes) maps each id to one class. So you have to watch out for the 'person-id' and drop all other lines in this and the other dictionaries

Comment: Thanks. I have finally done this. I am extracting all the classes with id `1` as it is the id of person, based on the scores so if score is less than 50% I am ignoring that id. In this way I am only detecting person. In order to remove bounding box, I have modified `visualization_utils.py` where I am ignoring all the bounding box and only showing box for person. At the end I am also counting the number of person detected based on scores and classes.

Comment: @SAndrew does the detection process speed up since it's always detecting all 90 categories? I wanted a way to tell the model to run only s specific list of classes, so that I could detect Person, Car only for example. Or the Models creators could add flexibility to retrained using a list of classes online and download only a model that would detect Person and Car as an example.