# How to detect only people as an object using Tensorflow API

Tags: tensorflow, detection

I am using Tensorflow API to detect object, however want to detect only people in boxes.

I tried solution that asked before, for instance : :[How to only detect humans in object detection API Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53281990/how-to-only-detect-humans-in-object-detection-api-tensorflow)

I dropped all other class except people but it did not work for me and also I changed the num_class as 1, it did not work also.

When I changed the num_class as 1, it returns to me boxes which named as NA.

Update : I use pre-trained model which is named "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco".

Answer (score 0):

I found out something after searching again on the stack overflow, I encounterd this [How can i use tensorflow object detection to only detect persons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888445/how-can-i-use-tensorflow-object-detection-to-only-detect-persons) and it solved my problem clearly.